# A list assignment problem, that has been messing with my code

Tags: python

could someone explain why this thing exists and how to counteract it

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b[1] = 0
print(a)
a = [1, 0, 3]
```

Its bugging me, because, when I use this with int, then it acts normally.

```
a = 1
b = a
b +=1
print(a)
a = 1
```

It`s really messing with some of my code
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is it that exists? What do you need to counteract? Your code looks fine.

Comment: I see you've added some more code. Still looks fine.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/4046632

Comment: Assignment never copies data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `b = a` you are having both point to the same spot in memory. Thus, changes to one will reflect in the other.

A simple fix to copy an array without them being connected:

```
b = a[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

`b = a` is making `b` a reference to the same list as `a`. Use

```
b = a.copy()
```

to make a separate list.